# Excel says "blank cells" are larger than a "percent value"

Tags: excel, vba

here's a really simple issue that is taking me hours to figure out.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

[image]

Comment: Did you do anything to cells B3 and C3? I opened a blank sheet, entered 50.00% in cell C3, formatted blank cell B3 to interior green, and typed your formula in cell B7. However, my answer in B7 is C3 is larger than B3.

Comment: Cell C3 is static, but B3's formula used to be =IF(ISERROR((B2-B1)/B1),"",(B2-B1)/B1)

Comment: With B3 = "", ISBLANK(B3) actually returns FALSE.

Comment: So, instead of using ISBLANK(B3) you may use B3 = ""

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, text values are larger than numbers. Try this: in a column enter the following values / formulas, one per row

```
a
b
c
=IF(TRUE(),"","")
5
4
3
```

So now you have text, a formula that returns an empty string and numbers. Use the Excel Sort functionality to sort these seven cells (Data > Sort > A to Z). The result is:

[image]

Any text value will be considered larger than any number. That is why the IF statement produces the result that you see.

You can turn the text into a number with the N() function, which will return 0 if the cell contains text or an empty string.

```
=IF(C3<N(B3),"C3 is smaller","B3 is smaller")
```

Comment: Beautiful advice on the N function-- never knew about that!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but it still does not explain why C3 is smaller than a "blank cell."

Any advice on why this is would still be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: By the definition of Excel, a string (even an empty one) is larger than any number. Your solution in this answer would be the correct one. If you still want to have B3 blank if B1 is blank too, format B3 to use a custom number format: `0.00%;-0.00%;;@`

Answer (score 0):

The issue perhaps `B3` contains blank space.

The `blank cell` is not really blank,it is contains some `nonprinting characters`.

Comment: Why is blank space larger than a fixed percentage?

Comment: What is a "can not print characters?" It is displaying what's inside these quotes, "" i.e. nothing.

Comment: If B3 contains space, ISBLANK(B3) will returns FALSE.

Comment: What is defined as "space" if it is displaying "" ?

Comment: Because the `blank space`'s code is 32, `code(B3)`=32.

Comment: Is there an alternative to make "blank space" null?

Comment: In "", there is no space. That why ISBLANK(B3) returns FALSE.

Comment: Sorry , that is called `nonprinting characters `. `https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d`, ` http://superuser.com/questions/529585/excel-2010-how-to-display-or-view-non-printing-characters`  and here `http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltextfunctions/ss/2013-06-22-excel-clean-function.htm`

Comment: @kelvin liaw : `""` is also characters.But in this situation,I think `B3` is contains `nonprinting characters` ,such as `char(127)`,`char(128)`...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, since your B3 may contain "" and assume your C3 is 50.00%, in B7 the formula can be:

```
=IF(B3="","C3>B3",IF(C3<B3,"C3<B3","C3>B3"))
```